# When mouseenter it shows me icons on all projectname

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a problem with mouseenter, I want when mouseenter to show me icons for that projectname i hovered, but in me it shows to all projects.
I want for each project hovered show me icons

Here you have some code.
This is .ts

```
 showIcons(project: Project) {
 this.isIconsVisible = !this.isIconsVisible;
```

This is in html

```
 <td (mouseenter)="showIcons()" (mouseleave)="showIcons()">
 {{project.name}}
 <div class ="row" *ngIf="isIconsVisible">
 <div class="fa fa-edit clickable edit-icon" (click)="editProject()">
 </div>
 <div class="fa fa-pencil clickable fa-fw" 
 (click)="openprojecteditdialog(project)"></div>
 <div class="fa fa-trash-o clickable delete-icon" 
 (click)="deleteProject(project)"></div>
 <div class="fa fa-files-o clickable copy-item" 
 (click)="copyProject(project)"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using one variable (isIconsVisible) for all projects.
What you want to do is atach isIconsVisible as a property to each project, and then work with that.

```
 <td (mouseenter)="showIcons()" (mouseleave)="showIcons(project)">
    {{project.name}}
    <div class ="row" *ngIf="project.isIconsVisible">
       <div class="fa fa-edit clickable edit-icon" (click)="editProject()">
       </div>
```

And your showIcons function

```
showIcons(project: Project) {
 if(!project.isIconsVisible) {  // This will also check if the property is null 
    project.isIconsVisible = true;
 } else {
    project.isIconsVisible = false;
 }
 // project.isIconsVisible = !this.isIconsVisible;
```

Alternatively initialize all project.isIconsVisible to false at the start, so you can use `project.isIconsVisible = !this.isIconsVisible;`

Comment: Thank you it works now but i have made some changes but thank you this was very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you forgot to put in the project at the showIcons function?

```
<td (mouseenter)="showIcons(project)" (mouseleave)="showIcons(project)">
```

I'm not an Angular expert though...

Comment: I tried this didn't work but any way thank you for your time.